# Disable Latex font in python output

Tags: fonts, latex, ipython

I run the following code in Ipython:

```
In [1] a=10
In [2] a
```

The output is printed in latex font. How can I disable the latex font for the outputs, as it is slow and oversized.

Comment: That doesn't produce latex output by default - are you using something from sympy that might have enabled it?

Comment: Yes I imported sympy. But I couldn't track what I did with sympy that print result in latex output. So I removed sympy `pip uninstall sympy`